# SSRS IIF statement to find if rounding up or down

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2014

I've found multiple ways to format a rounded number, but what I am looking for is how to tell which way a number is rounded, specifically in SSRS 2014:

```
=IIF(Round(Fields!IMPERVIOUS_AREA.Value/4000,2,MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)=Floor(0),"Round Up","Round Down")
```

I would like to see in my results *5.73* to be "Rounded Up" and *2.09* to be "Rounded Down", but all I keep getting is "Rounded Down". I've tried putting `=Ceiling(0)` and `=Floor(0)` in my statement, hoping it could evaluate true or false.

Comment: So it looks like the zero (0) is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Ceiling(value)` always rounds up to the nearest integer.
`Round(value)` decides which way to round based on the common rules.

So it follows that testing if `Ceiling(value) = Round(value)` will tell you whether the value was rounded up.

```
=IIF(Ceiling(value) = Floor(value), "Value was already an integer.", IIF(Ceiling(value) = Round(value), "Value was Rounded Up.", "Value was Rounded Down."))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compare rounded and not rounded value. That allows you to see the direction of the movement:

```
=IIF(Round(value) > value, 
    "Rounded Up",
    IIF(Round(value) < value, 
        "Rounded Down", 
        "No rounding"))
```